# Optimization bug in Apple's LLVM, or bug in code?

Tags: ios, gcc, llvm, compiler-optimization

I have some iOS C++ code that compiles correctly on my local machine (LLVM 9.0) but compiles incorrectly on my build server (LLVM 10.0). The project is generated via CMake (same version on both) so the code being compiled is the same, with the same compiler settings.

After finally realizing that some critical values weren't being updated on the LLVM10 version I investigated the assembly and found out it was completely skipping part of the code.

```
void                    SceneDisplay::SetSize(const math::Vec2 &Size)
{
    m_Size = Size;

    m_ScreenWidth = int(m_Size.x * float(GraphicsUtil::WIDTH));
    m_ScreenHeight = int(m_Size.y * float(GraphicsUtil::HEIGHT));

    UpdateOffsetScale();
}
```

m_Size is initialized to 1.0,1.0 in the class constructor. This works fine and everything is perfect with LLVM9 - with LLVM10 we get the following disassembly:

```
    pushq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    __ZN12GraphicsUtil6HEIGHTE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax        
    movq    __ZN12GraphicsUtil5WIDTHE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx        
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)                        
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
Ltmp2347:
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    (%rdi), %rdi
    movq    %rdi, 56(%rsi)
    movl    (%rcx), %edx
    movl    %edx, 12(%rsi)
    movl    (%rax), %edx
    movl    %edx, 16(%rsi)
    movq    (%rsi), %rax
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    callq    *136(%rax)
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

As you can see the assignment of the two member variables is completely 'optimized' to just assume that m_Size.x and m_Size.y are 1.0 - thus just copying the values of GraphicsUtil::WIDTH and HEIGHT.

I fixed this by changing the code to use "Size" instead of "m_Size" for those assignments, as well as making them volatile just in case. But I'm wondering if there is a legitimate compiler error here or I'm missing something?

Edit: It should be noted that m_Size is nearly never 1.0,1.0

Edit2: The correct assembly for the assignments, as generated on my machine (different arch though, not able to get the same arch as above right now)

```
    str         x8, [x0, #56]
    lsr         x9, x8, #32
    fmov        s0, w8
    adrp        x8, __ZN12GraphicsUtil5WIDTHE@GOTPAGE
    ldr         x8, [x8, __ZN12GraphicsUtil5WIDTHE@GOTPAGEOFF]
    ldr         s1, [x8]
    ucvtf       s1, s1
    fmul        s0, s0, s1
    fcvtzs      w8, s0
    str         w8, [x0, #12]
    fmov        s0, w9
    adrp        x8, __ZN12GraphicsUtil6HEIGHTE@GOTPAGE
    ldr         x8, [x8, __ZN12GraphicsUtil6HEIGHTE@GOTPAGEOFF]
    ldr         s1, [x8]
    ucvtf       s1, s1
    fmul        s0, s0, s1
    fcvtzs      w8, s0
    str         w8, [x0, #16]
```

Comment: Don't see any `1`s in the assembly, TBH. But do see loads like `__ZN12GraphicsUtil6HEIGHTE@GOTPCREL`. What's wrong?

Comment: If you look at the C++ original, it should be multiplied by m_Size.x and m_Size.y. These values are nearly never 1.0, but due to the erroneous optimization, it is assumed that they are both always 1.0 - which means the value is loaded and "multiplied by 1.0" then stored in the result, ie it just loads and stores the value instead of doing what is actually written in the code.

Comment: Ah, right. How `GraphicsUtil::WIDTH` is declared, then?

Comment: It is a static float. I do not have access to the same disassembly right this minute but I've amended with the correct arm64 assembly for the same assignment.

Comment: I think what you ought to do is make a bug report for LLVM (well, the Apple version). A small, self-contained thing that'll either cause a duh moment in yourself or give Apple a way to reproduce and fix this. IMO both outcomes are >10% probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a minimal test case I was able to confirm it's definitely a compiler bug.

Conditions: No other piece of code modifies m_Size, m_Size is initialized `math::Vec2 m_Size{1.0, 1.0};`. It works perfectly on every version of LLVM I could find before 10.0, seems some sort of regression occurred at that version.

Have submitted to Apple's LLVM team and llvm.org.

Thanks for comments.

Comment: For others, it helps to give a link to the bug report (at least the one on llvm.org should be public).

Comment: Will update the post in a bit - I bluffed slightly as llvm.org has slightly more complex rules for submitting a bug, still working on it :) Apple doesn't seem to expose a public bug list.